# Can you plot complex maps?

Tags: plotting, complex

I want to plot $|z+1|=|z-2+i|$/ Is there any way to do this without converting it to Cartesian form and contour plotting?

Comment: "without converting it to cartesian form" - no. Why isn't `ContourPlot[Abs[x + I y + 1] == Abs[x + I y - 2 + I], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]` satisfactory?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Comment: You can square both sides and $z\overline{z}$ will cancel.  Then you can plot in Cartesian or polar coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

I often want to do what you are asking for, and here is how I do it

```
curve = Abs[z + 1] == Abs[z - 2 + I];

Block[{z = x + I y}, 
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[curve], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]]
```

[image: Contour plot]

We use `Block` to localise the value of `z`.  We need to `Evaluate` `curve` before it shows up.

Comment: Not sure why you want to avoid Cartesian coordinates, but if you convert to polar coordinates, you"ll get the same result mikado plotted, a straight line.

Comment: The result  is $\Re \{ ze^{i \vartheta} \}= a$.  From this, you can find the slope of the line, and a point on the line, and plot it.  If this is what you are asking, and if the question is reopened, and if more details are needed, ...